# Geometrical Inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, analysis, inequality

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral on the unit circle, and the diagonals
$AC$ and $BD$ intersects at $E$. If the shortest height of the
triangle $ACD$ equals the radius of the incircle of the triangle $ABE$
that is denoted by $r$, is $r$ less than $0.4$?

Comment: or is $r$ less than $\frac{1}{4} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)$? Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: Please do leave comments before down voting.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: Why do you think it will be less than any number?